# How to achieve dynamic url tree in NextJS

Tags: typescript, api, url, react-router, next.js

From what I understand from nextjs routes -

blog->[id].jsx gives "blog/1", "blog/2" etc.

But I want to achieve page-subpage-subpage kind of url tree where each page can have subpages & subpages can have further subpages. So url's may look like these -

"page/sub-page/sub-sub-page" etc.

I'm using django treebeard in backend, so pages & subpages urls are all dynamic & comes from API calls. Currently I tried with the below structure -

- pages/

  - index.js
  - [slug].js

It only gives me ability to fetch only level one pages. I want to acquire multi-level page access.

Anybody ever did it? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL tree is based on the folders and files in your pages-folder, so you can simply add folders and files to make the tree you need. For example, a blog could have a structure of folders and files like this:

- pages/

  - index.js *(blogsite.com)*
  - blog/

    - index.js *(blogsite.com/blog)*
    - [id]/

      - index.js *(blogsite.com/blog/123)*
      - comments/

        - index.js *(blogsite.com/blog/123/comments)*
        - [commentId].js *(blogsite.com/blog/123/comments/321)*

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:**

I missed that the asker actually meant that they don't know the depth of their tree beforehand. In this case you can use a [catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) like [...id] and the page will get all of the parameters that exist in the query-object.

Comment: I already know that, my pages have unlimited level of sub-pages, so I don't know how deep I need to go. Following this structure, I have to set the limit of sub-page levels, like pages/[id]/[id]/[id], so my sub-page level is only 3.

Comment: Ah, got it! You can make that happen with [catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes).

Comment: Thanks brother @sansar, I don't know how I missed that from their doc, but it was just the piece I was looking for.